# Why is the relationship between max(X,Y) and X and Y the way it is?

Tags: probability, random-variable, subset

[image]

My textbook says that the above follows from the observation:

**$\{W\leq w\}=\{X\leq w\},\{Y\leq w\}$,**

How do we prove the above observation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If maximum of $X$ and $Y$ is smaller than a particular number, let's say, $w$; then both of the numbers should be smaller than $w$. If any of them was larger than $w$, then maximum of them would also be larger than $w$. So, the set of $X,Y$ pairs both $\leq w$ is equal to the set of $(X,Y)$ pairs, for which $max(X,Y)\leq w$, thus yielding the same probability, i.e.

$$P(W\leq w)=P(X\leq w,Y\leq w)$$